# VB.NET paint application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, paint, draw, picturebox

I'm facing two problems in my application:

- The Undo Function
- The Drawing Part

When i draw on the picturebox , it draws very well, when - let's say I want to undo an action, it undo's it but when I click back on the picturebox it reacts like a redo function ,all the drawings appear back on the image.

the second problem is : i want to be able to edit a picture so i load a image by clicking on a listview item but due to something i'm missing the image it is not show but instead it shows a white background in which i am able to draw.

bellow is the code i am using

```
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

Public Class Form1
    Public drawgraph, g As Graphics
    Private redoBuffer As New Stack(Of Image)()
    Private undoBuffer As New Stack(Of Image)()
    Dim color As Color
    Dim UndoStack As New Stack(Of Bitmap)()
    Dim xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd As Integer
    Public Drawbitmap As Bitmap
    Dim Drawgraphics As Graphics
    Dim myPen As New Pen(color.Black, 4)
    Dim myColor As Color = color.Black
    Dim myPenWidth As Integer
    Dim myBGColor As Color = color.White
    Dim Drawing As Boolean

    Private Sub drawMyline()

        PictureBox4.Image = Drawbitmap
        Drawgraphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        Drawgraphics.DrawLine(myPen, xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd)

    End Sub

    Private Sub PushUndo(ByVal b As Bitmap)
        UndoStack.Push(b)
    End Sub
    Private Function PopUndo() As Bitmap
        If UndoStack.Count = 0 Then
            Return Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
        If UndoStack.Count > 0 Then
            Return UndoStack.Pop
        End If

    End Function



    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Drawbitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox4.Width, PictureBox4.Height)
        Drawgraphics = Graphics.FromImage(Drawbitmap)
        PictureBox4.Image = Drawbitmap
        Drawgraphics.Clear(color.White)
         myPenWidth = NumericUpDown1.Value
        xStart = -1
        yStart = -1
        Drawing = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox7.Click
        Dim bmp As Bitmap
        bmp = PopUndo()
        If bmp IsNot Nothing Then
            PictureBox4.Image = bmp
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox4_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.MouseDown
        Drawing = True
        PushUndo(PictureBox4.Image.Clone)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox4_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.MouseUp
        Drawing = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox4_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.MouseMove
        If Drawing Then
            xStart = e.X
            yStart = e.Y
            drawMyline()
        End If
        xEnd = e.X
        yEnd = e.Y
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried making changes but i can't load the image i want into the picturebox4 and draw on it , it always loads a white background as for the undo function it works until a click again on picturebox4 and all the undone drawings appear back. Can someone help me fix this 2 problems that I have?

Comment: firstly, change the title to something relevant. Saying "hello" in the title doesn't add any value. Secondly, trim down the snippets of code to the relevant sections and remove "noise" in the question, like: "let me tell you what happens .", " Please i have been trying and failing for about 3 days."

Comment: thank you , i did not notice that i had mistakes .